# Windows PE from Visual C++ compiler debug database

Tags: visual-c++, portable-executable, hexdump

I complied a very simple application, it just prints out hell world to a C++ Win32 console. I came across a reference to the debug database file in HxD, never noticed it before, I was building it for "debug" and not "release". I changed this, the release executable also includes this reference.

Does anyone know if I am doing something wrong as far as if I was going to release this, I build it for release right? What would be the "proper" way to build a executable for release.

I also see some project assembly XML further down, I am interested in minimizing the Windows PE executable, am I right to think there must be complier options? Maybe this is all to do with the IDE and using just a text editor and barebones complier is what I am looking for?

[image: HxD screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even in release mode Visual C++ will generate a program database (*.PDB ; the full path is embedded in the binary and can be used by some debuggers) and a manifest file (the XML you see in your executable).

**Disable PDB generation**

- In Visual C++, go to your project properties (`Edit` > `xxx Properties` [ALT+F7]).
- In your project properties go to `Configuration Properties` > `Linker` > `Debugging`
- Set `Generate Debug info` to `No` (it should say `Yes (/DEBUG)` by default)

Warning: You'll now not have any symbols while debugging.

**Disable Manifest file**

- In Visual C++, go to your project properties (`Edit` > `xxx Properties` [ALT+F7]).
- In your project properties go to `Configuration Properties` > `Linker` > `Manifest File`
- Set `Generate Manifest` to `No` (it should say `Yes (/MANIFEST)` by default)

You might also want to check properties in `Configuration Properties` > `Manifest tool`.

Warning: manifests are notably used for DLL side-by-side loading, COM isolation and User Access control. Make sure that your executable runs fine when Manifest generation has been disabled.

There are various tricks to reduce a PE file (besides obvious compression) to get a minimal file right from compiler and linker passes, these tricks are well known in the demoscene, some of them are [explained here](http://andrewl.dreamhosters.com/archive/60094446.txt). Bear in mind that it comes with some drawbacks and need thorough testing to see if the resulting PE file behaves correctly.